# Unable to find special symbol for single and double window icon

Tags: symbols, word-to-latex

I would like to get the symbols shown in the text below in latex

[image]

This is what I was able to achieve

[image]

From the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

Please tick (\checkmark) the appropriate answer within the 5 Likert scale ( ? strongly disagree; ? disagree; $\blacktriangleleft$ Undecided; $\blacktriangleright$ agree and $\blacktriangle$ strongly agree) 

\end{document}
```

I am unable to find symbols for a single and double window.

Comment: Presumably they are Microsoft Windows related symbols, which are of course included in MS Word. For something similar, see the documentation of the `pifont` package [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf), in particular table 2 on page 7, you may find pictograms close enough `111` - `114` for instance.

Comment: @BMWurm I suggest you make that answer

Comment: @AndrewSwann I thought about making it an answer back then, but technically it isn't one, because it does in fact *not* provide what was asked for. I had actually assumed, somebody would provide a way to include the MS Windows font in question. But this version might still be helpful and the comment might get deleted, so I'll get to it...

Answer (score 2):

<sub>As suggested by [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann), I turned [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281942/unable-to-find-special-symbol-for-single-and-double-window-icon?noredirect=1#comment679563_281942) into an answer.</sub>

The symbols you are looking for are - presumably - Microsoft Windows related symbols, which are of course easily used in MS Word.

If you can figure out which font provides them and you're using (Xe/Lua)LaTeX anyway, the [Fontspec package](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) should do the trick in getting the actual symbols into your text.

For something similar with pdfLaTeX, see the documentation of the [pifont package](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf), in particular table 2 on page 7, where you may find pictograms close enough [111 - 114 for instance].